# Finished message - TLS1.3-draft(28)

Tags: encryption, tls

In TLS 1.3 , while computing Finished message,

```
finished_key = HKDF-Expand-Label(BaseKey, "finished", "", Hash.length)
```

How can **"finished"** be used for this calculation as it is the objective of this process or it signifies anything other that I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-28#section-7.1 for the definition of HKDF-Expand-Label in TLS 1.3:

> HKDF-Expand-Label(Secret, Label, Context, Length) =
> HKDF-Expand(Secret, HkdfLabel, Length)
>
> Where HkdfLabel is specified as:
>
> ```
> struct {
>     uint16 length = Length;
>     opaque label<7..255> = "tls13 " + Label;
>     opaque context<0..255> = Context;
> } HkdfLabel;
> ```

The string "finished" is used as part of the label.